# How to use blob data type in an interactive grid

Tags: oracle-apex

I've created master detail page, master region use table which has logo column, which is blob data type.

When I want to start application, I get error -  cannot convert BLOB to VARCHAR2.

apex_error_code: WWV_FLOW_EXEC.CAN_NOT_CONVERT_TO_VARCHAR2

How can I display blob file or how can I avoid this error?

This master-detail page is only for read with link on id(with modal dialog), I tried to use blob in interactive report, it works. 
Can I use interactive report as master detail?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Goku, did you still need help with this or did Chaitanya’s answer work? If it worked, please accept the answer for future viewers.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to display blob download link. You can implement this using the APEX_UTIL.GET_BLOB_FILE_SRC function. See the example [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.1/aeapi/GET_BLOB_FILE_SRC-Function.html#GUID-21F2D33A-A616-48B5-BAF5-A85C0EDC998F).